# update_post_meta returning false when called during init

Tags: post-meta, init

Given a custom URL like:

```
http://clientsite.com/tvt?pmc_task=member_check&post_id=1041&user=3851&status=approved
```

I'm trying to catch the URL and add the user_id to a custom post meta field.

My code looks like:

```
function add_user_to_tvt(){

    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

    $current_members = get_post_meta( absint( $post_id ), '_pmc_members', true );
    $current_members[] = $user_id;
    $unique = array_unique( $current_members );

    $value = update_post_meta( absint( $post_id ), '_pmc_members', $unique );

    if ( false === $value ){
        $message = 'You were not added. Please contact an administrator';
        $success = false;
    } else {
        $message = 'You were added to the team. Refresh the page to see your name.';
        $success = true;
    }

    $values = array(
        'success' => $success,
        'message' => $message,
    );

    return (array) $values;

} // add_user_to_tvt

add_action( 'init', 'add_user_to_tvt' );
```

The problem is that when I open a new tab and put in the URL update_post_meta returns false and so the feedback given to the user is that it failed even though, it did in fact update.

If I refresh that same page with the URL sitting in the browser, update_post_meta returns the expected value and the proper feedback is returned to the user.

Yes I am handling the fact that update_post_meta returns false if the current value and the value you're trying to update are the same. We don't even call the function above if the value already exists.

**Update** so it seems that this does work as expected and return the values properly if we delay the check till the template_redirect action. In which case, things work for me now (woohoo) but I've always caught URL and such via the 'init' hook.

Should we not be doing that?

**Update**: I realize init doesn't pass $post_id or $user_id. This is a simplified version of the code that doesn't work. We catch these 2 values and pass it to the function above. I just moved the 'catch' inside the function to keep things short.

Comment: `init` is way to early. Try `template_include` or similar

Comment: And why is that the place to do this versus init? What portion of the WordPress lifecycle is needed?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but `init` doesn't pass `$post_id` or `$user_id` to the callback, so if you're not using `WP_DEBUG` you're probably missing some function call errors. Same with expecting the `$_GET` vars to be there on every load.

Comment: Yup @NateWr I know that. I don't rely on init, this is just making it simple for StackExchange to see.

Comment: The comment by @NateWr is why `init` won't work here. The post object has not yet being set when `init` fires. By the time `template_include` (you can also use `template_redirect` here which is more preferable, was a bit to hasty here) fires, the post object has been set up and the main query has run

Comment: @PieterGoosen as I said, I'm not relying on init to pass any values, and in fact update_post_meta updates, it just doesn't return the proper values.